# Export solutions of partial differential equation in mathematica

Tags: differential-equations, export, finite-element-method

I have a system of coupled first order partial differential equations. Minimal code is shown below:

```
de1 = D[f[t, p], t] == 
   p/t D[ 1/3 f[t, p] + 2/15 g[t, p], p] + 2/5 1/t g[t, p];
de2 = D[g[t, p], t] == 
   p/t D[11/21 g[t, p] + 2/3 f[t, p], p] + 2/7 1/t g[t, p] - g[t, p];
IC = {f[t0, p] == Exp[-p], g[t0, p] == 1/2 Exp[-p]};

t0 = 0.1;
sol = NDSolve[{de1, de2, IC}, {f, g}, {t, t0, 1}, {p, 10^-2, 10}, 
   Method -> {"MethodOfLines", "TemporalVariable" -> t, 
     "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", 
       "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.5}}}] // Flatten
```

First, note that the initial conditions are only specified on one boundary.
I want to export the values of functions f and g at specific t (say t1) in format {p, f(t1,p), g(t1,p)}. Also, is it possible to export at any t1 (not just at the evaluated grid)?

I am newbie in solving PDE's. Any suggestions to improve the code is much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**modified**

The result of `NDSolve` offers interpolation functions, which might be evaluated at arbitrary gridpoints.

Try

```
{F, G} = NDSolveValue[{de1, de2, IC}, {f, g}, {t, t0, 1}, {p,10^-2,10}, Method -> {"MethodOfLines", "TemporalVariable" -> t,"SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement","MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.5}}}] // Flatten

grid=Table[{t,p,F[t,p],G[t,p]},{t,Subdivide[t0,1,10]},{p,Subdivide[10^-2,10,  10]}]
```

This works too in a predefined spatial mesh:

```
n = 10;
meshp = ToElementMesh[Table[{10^-2 + (10 - 10^-2 ) ((i - 1)/( n - 1 ))^2}, {i, 1,n}]]
{F, G} = NDSolveValue[{de1, de2, IC}, {f, g}, {t, t0, 1}
,Element[p, meshp],Method -> {"MethodOfLines", "TemporalVariable" -> t,"SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement","MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.5}}}] //Flatten
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Precisely what I wanted.

Comment: You're welcome. Alternatively if you intend to use the result of `NDSolve` in another Mathematica session perhaps `DumpSave` might be helpful!

Comment: Thanks. On a related question, is it possible to specify nonuniform (say exponential) grid in MeshOptions?

Comment: @SunilJaiswal `NDSolve` works in a predefined mesh too. See my modified answer!

Comment: Thanks again! Works after including the package ``<< NDSolve`FEM`` .